# detecting leaks in central vacuum

Tags: central-vacuum

As part of a room remodel, I had to move the central vacuum power unit.     Now, the suction appears to have decreased a little.  The most obvious culprit is leaking joints in the pipes, in fact, I don't know what else it could be.  (It's especially annoying because I incidentally did a few things that should've improved performance a wee bit - removed a few bends in the pipes, lowered the unit a little, since most pipes are in crawlspace).

So my question is: what's the best way to determine if the suction is really lessened (without, unfortunately, having measured it before the work), and - more importantly - what's the best way to locate any leaks in the system ?

Comment: The pipes fit so tightly into the fittings, that it seems like even forgetting to put PVC on one of the joints, should have minimal effect on the suction.

Comment: Did you try to put in a new collection bag and clean any secondary filters. Our central vac has a secondary filter that needs to be cleaned annually.

Comment: Turn it on and use a smoke source (e.g. incense stick) to look for leaks?

Comment: @d.george my power unit is an HP Vacuflo which is a "cyclonic" type, so it requires no collection bag, just a big bucket at the bottom.   There is a coarse screen above that, below the motor, that you're supposed to brush off whenever you empty the bucket.   I've done all that.   But yeah, the only other culprit besides leaky pipes would be the power unit not operating at full strength.   But I changed absolutely nothing about it.   Ran a new dedicated circuit, I guess I should check the voltage on it.

Comment: Is the new location closer to the outlets, or farther?

Comment: I literally just moved the power unit a few feet - it was limiting good access to the breaker panel - so it's no closer or farther away from either the electrical supply or the vacuum outlets.  Checked voltage at the outlet: 124vac, drops about a volt with unit running.   Gotta be a leak somewhere.